# What's the best way to fix carbon to titanium?

Tags: adhesive, diy-vs-pro

I'm building (experimenting if you wish) something out of the old bike parts and I need to fix two parts together one titanium and one carbon.

Basically the parts are two tubes one made of carbon of a lower diameter and one made of titanium. So the carbon tube goes inside the titanium tube and I need to find a way to fix it inside for good. I guess it should be some kind of a hardcore gluing.

If anyone have any experience or suggestions please share. Thank you!

Comment: How much smaller is the carbon tube than the titanium tube? I mean, does it fit snugly (ie: ID of titanium tube is nearly the same size as the OD of the carbon tube)? Or is there a lot of gap?

Comment: @Paulster2 yeah they fit each other pretty tight with a minimum gap

Answer (score 2):

I found this answer for you on [this forum](http://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=230923):

> [Henkel/Loctite's Hysol series](http://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/00611699?src=pla&cid=PLA-Google-PLA+-+Test&CS_003=7867724&CS_010=00611699) and [3M's Scotch-Weld epoxies](http://www.ellsworth.com/products/by-manufacturer/3m/adhesives/epoxy/3m-scotch-weld-1751-epoxy-adhesive-gray-2-oz-tube-kit/) are good choices.  Surface preparation is critical.  Review standards on this subject for best practices: *ASTM D 2651 Standard Guide for Preparation of Metal Surfaces for Adhesive Bonding and ISO 17212 Structural adhesives -- Guidelines for the surface preparation of metals and plastics prior to adhesive bonding.*

These two links were also included:

- [Standard Guide for Preparation of Metal Surfaces for Adhesive Bonding](http://www.astm.org/Standards/D2651.htm)
- [Structural adhesives -- Guidelines for the surface preparation of metals and plastics prior to adhesive bonding](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=38283)

Comment: why one is $20 and another is $50? I guess more expensive one is tougher right? or not necessarily?

Comment: @LoomyBear ... I wouldn't think one better over the other. It could be the source of the product which is causing the higher cost, or it could be the brand name itself causing the price difference. I would bet each would work about the same ... just throwing out the different options which the original post had in them.

Comment: It might be good to do a little more research. One may be more resilient and/or flexible/tough, while the other may be more resistant to impacts. Most adhesives are **either** resistant to impact **or** flexible/tough. It may depend on your intended use which is best suited.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk ... fair point. As long as there is little slop between the two pieces, this is where the strength will really come from though. The epoxy is just there to keep them from moving. I would not recommend *not* doing further research, though, just to determine which would work better in the OP's mind.